# How many distinct (non-isomorphic) field extensions of degree n are there?

Tags: number-theory

My study group ha raised an interesting question. Up to isomorphism, how many field extensions of degree n are there? Since a field extension is by definition a vector space, they are all isomorphic as such but are they isomorphic as number fields?

Comment: What do you mean "as number fields"?

Answer (score 5):

For finite fields, we have uniqueness.

For the characteristic $0$ case, we already have countably many quadratic extensions of the rationals (e.g. $\mathbb Q[\sqrt p]$ with $p$ prime are pairwise different) an the same holds for finite $n>2$.

Comment: But are these not trivially isomorphic by mapping p to q? (p and q distinct primes)

Comment: I thought I had already made this point. Somehow it disappeared! Aren't these isomorphic extensions by simply mapping different primes to each other. I.E. Q(sqrt(3) is isopmorphic to Q(sqrt(5) is it not?

Comment: @DavidDyer Shouldn't then $\sqrt{q}$ be a root of $X^2 -p$ if there were a field morphism taking $\sqrt{p}\mapsto \sqrt{q}$? I take it you meant $\sqrt{p}\mapsto \sqrt{q}$, because $p\mapsto q$ makes no sense as $p$ and $q$ are in the prime field.